# Can NLTK Data be installed in AWS Redshift environment?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, nltk, amazon-redshift, textblob

I am trying to create a Python user defined scalar (UDF) function in an AWS Redshift DB. The UDF wraps the following Python code:

```
CREATE or replace library nltk language plpythonu from 's3://xxx/dev/python-libraries/nltk-3.2.1.zip'
credentials 'aws_access_key_id=xxx;aws_secret_access_key=yyy' region as 'eu-west-1';

CREATE or replace library textblob language plpythonu from 's3://xxx/dev/python-libraries/textblob-0.15.1-py2.py3-none-any.zip'
credentials 'aws_access_key_id=xxx;aws_secret_access_key=yyy' region as 'eu-west-1';

CREATE or replace FUNCTION f_sentiment_polarity (comment varchar(1000)) RETURNS float IMMUTABLE as $$
from textblob import TextBlob
return TextBlob(comment).sentiment.polarity
$$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;

SELECT f_sentiment_polarity('this would be very useful if the corpora were loaded');

f_sentiment_polarity
--------------------
                   0
```

The result of the `select` statement gives me `0`

When I run the same Python code in a local environment (Python 2.7 on Windows with NLTK v3.2.5, I get `0.39`:

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, May 23 2015, 09:44:00) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from textblob import TextBlob
>>> TextBlob('this would be very useful if the corpora were loaded').sentiment.polarity
0.39
>>>
```

I presume that this is because the various NLTK Corpora have not been loaded in the AWS Redshift Python environment.  Creating another Redshift UDF as follows seems to bear this out:

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION f_num_brown_words () RETURNS int IMMUTABLE as $$
from nltk.corpus import brown
return len(brown.words())
$$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;

select f_num_brown_words();

ERROR: XX000: LookupError: 
**********************************************************************
  Resource u'corpora/brown' not found.  Please use the NLTK
  Downloader to obtain the resource:  >>> nltk.download()
  Searched in:
    - "'/'/nltk_data"
    - '/usr/shar
```

Question: Is there a way of loading the NLTK Corpora in the AWS Redshift Python environment so that my UDF will function correctly?

Comment: you cannot access external data - it is not allowed.

Comment: Can redshift servers host file storage? Or interact with a remote storage? It's possible to point the NLTK another location if a remote disk is mounted locally with `nltk.data.path.append`

Answer (score 0):

You can load custom libraries onto your cluster, more info in the [official docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/udf-python-language-support.html).

I followed the instructions and it worked for me with another library.

Comment: Hi Alex, Yes I've loaded two libraries textblob and its dependency nltk. However nltk requires some data (Corpora) to be downloaded and it's not clear if or how this can be done in the Redshift environment.